# Ajax form submitting to two scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Basically i have a single form that i want to pass variables to two separate php scripts for processing on submit. What I have done works seems to work fine for my purposes, I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this inside of one jquery script instead of having to repeat the script and changing the URL as i have done. Or is the way iv gone about it fine? cant find many examples of this usage on Google but maybe I'm not searching the right things. Also if I'm doing something that is bad practice please let me know, I'm very new to Ajax and every tutorial i follow seems to do things differently.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sform').submit(function(){

        // show that something is loading
        $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

        /*
         * 'post_receiver.php' - where you will pass the form data
         * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
         * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
         */
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'move_to_lease.php', 
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })



        .done(function(data){

            // show the response
            $('#response').html(data);

        })



        .fail(function() {

            // just in case posting your form failed
            alert( "Posting failed." );

        });

        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
        return false;

    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sform').submit(function(){

        // show that something is loading
        $('#txtHint').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

        /*
         * 'post_receiver.php' - where you will pass the form data
         * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
         * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
         */
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'show_lease_sub.php', 
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){

            // show the response
            $('#txtHint').html(data);

        })
        .fail(function() {

            // just in case posting your form failed
            alert( "Posting failed." );

        });

        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
        return false;

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: There's no need to repeat the entire function - you could just make two successive AJAX calls within one function. However, one has to ask why your serverside script doesn't handle all the required processing in one script?

Comment: I need two forms to operate separately. one submits the data entered into it and the other is an Ajax select box that is used to display a visual representation of an oyster lease. This select box needs to be able to show any number of different leases in a specified div and that is why it is separate to the main form. however i need this div to update when the main form is submitted so as to show the new entries in the display. that is why i have done it like this. When you say "make two successive AJAX calls"  do you mean i data to say data2?

Comment: Presumably your second PHP script is relying on data that is updated by the first. If so you don't need to submit the data a second time, but you have a race condition since you're effectively submitting two requests at once and you can't be sure that the first AJAX call will complete before the second AJAX call requests new data. Either your first call should handle updates and return the new data set (one AJAX call, one script) or the second call should be fired in the `.done()` method of the first to guarantee the right sequence. There appears to be more here than your question implies.

Comment: Sorry maybe Im not explaining myself well enough, this might help.

[link]http://www.portstephenswebstudio.com.au/xloysters/trying_to_do.jpg

Comment: From the image you provided, you need to make two complete different AJAX calls.

Comment: @Matt - Your image/explaination doesn't match your code. Unless both of your forms have the same id - in which case, you've got a bigger problem. So is it one form or two? If it's one form, and you're passing the exact same data, consolidate your ajax into a single function like in my answer. If it's two forms, change the ID of one of them and leave  everything else alone.

Comment: Maybe im a bit silly. Brains fried now. The txthint area can be updated by the select box at anytime. when the form is submitted originally it didn't update the txthint area and it wouldn't show the changed been made by a user until that user selected a different option in the select box on the far right and then selected the lease again to refresh it. Now the txthint area is refreshed on submit of the form. I understand that i could simply update the txthint area with the "lease" select box in the main form but  users needs to look at other leases while they are filling out the form.

Comment: I give up man. You're not making sense. Just make two different calls for each action. Sounds like you're over thinking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice would be to handle both calls with one back-end script. You could return 2 separate responses by utilizing an array. Protip - Write a class.

*ajax.php*

```
class leaseStuff{
    public static function moveToLease($data){
        // add code from move_to_lease.php, change $_POST to $data
    }
    public static function showLeaseSub($data){
        // add code from show_lease_sub.php, change $_POST to $data
    }
}

echo json_encode(array(
    "moveToLease"=>leaseStuff::moveToLease($_POST),
    "showLeaseSub"=>leaseStuff::showLeaseSub($_POST)
));
```

Then you can consolidate your Ajax into one call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php', 
    data: $(this).serialize()
}).done(function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#response').html(data.moveToLease);
    $('#txtHint').html(data.showLeaseSub);
});
```

Comment: Ill give that a try thanks, will take some time to get my head around though. Seems to be the solution im after.

Comment: @Matt, you can pretty much copy your exiting scripts into the functions of the class, just don't echo the html, instead, `return` it.

Comment: @Matt also, anywhere it says `$_POST`, change it to $data. Other than that, just copy this word for word. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through an array with your URLs:

```
$('#sform').submit(function () {
    var urls = [
                    {
                        "url": "move_to_lease.php",
                        "response_id": "#response"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "show_lease_sub.php",
                        "response_id": "#txtHint"
                    }
                ]


    for (var k in urls) {
        $(urls[k].response_id).html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: urls[k].url,
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function (data) {
            $(urls[k].response_id).html(data);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Posting failed.");
        });
    }

    return false;

});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

based on the image you provided **[IMAGE](http://www.portstephenswebstudio.com.au/xloysters/trying_to_do.jpg)**, you need to make two different AJAX calls.

1. When the form is submitted:
   ->save info to DB
   ->get info to update the display
2. when the select dropdown is changed:
   ->get the information from the DB
   ->get info to update the display

Comment: Sorry that seems to refresh the whole page but then does nothing.

Comment: Try it now, and let me know what you get

Comment: Still the same sorry.